# Problems in form with three dependent combos en React JS

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-props

I'm having "props.options.map is not a function" problem in a react app with three dependent combos.

The code of App.js which has a main ComboApp function with three hooks:

communitiesValue
provincesOptions,
municipalitiesOptions

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Comunidades from './components/comunidades';
import Provincias from "./components/provincias";
import Municipios from "./components/municipios";

let comunidadSeleccionada, provinciaSeleccionada, municipioSeleccionado;

const ComboApp = () => {
  const [comunidadesValue, setComunidadesValue]= useState("");
  const [provinciasOpciones, setProvinciasOpciones]= useState([]);
  const [municipiosOpciones, setMunicipiosOpciones]= useState([]);
```

The function that loads the first combo is the next:

```
  const handleComunidadesChange = (event) =>{

    // We link to the change event

    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    comunidadSeleccionada = selectedValue;

    document.getElementById('mensaje').innerHTML = '';

    setComunidadesValue(selectedValue);

    switch(selectedValue){
      case 'Euskadi':
          setProvinciasOpciones(['Araba','Bizkaia','Gipuzkoa']);
          break;
       case 'Aragon':
          setProvinciasOpciones(['Zaragoza','Huesca','Teruel']);
          break;  
       case 'Canarias':
           setProvinciasOpciones(['Las Palmas','Tenerife']);
           break;  
       default: setProvinciasOpciones([]);  
    }
  };
```

The one that fills the second combo:

```
  const handleProvinciasChange = (event) =>{

    // We link to the change event
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    provinciaSeleccionada = selectedValue;

    document.getElementById('mensaje').innerHTML = '';

    setProvinciasOpciones(selectedValue);

    switch(selectedValue){
      case 'Araba':
        setMunicipiosOpciones(['Gasteiz','Laguardia','Oion']);
        break;
       case 'Bizkaia':
          setMunicipiosOpciones(['Bilbo','Barakaldo','Durango']);
          break;  
       case 'Gipuzkoa':
          setMunicipiosOpciones(['Donosti','Arrasate','Eibar']);
        break;  
        default: setMunicipiosOpciones([]);     
    }
  };


  return(<>
    <div>
      <Comunidades handleChange={handleComunidadesChange}/>{" "}
      <br/>
      <Provincias opciones={provinciasOpciones} handleChange={handleProvinciasChange}/>{" "}
      <br/>
      <Municipios opciones={municipiosOpciones} handleChange={handleMunicipiosChange}/>{" "}
    </div>
    <div id="mensaje"></div>
  </>
  );
};

export default ComboApp;
```

The first combo is filled without problems. When trying to fill in the second appears:

"props.opciones.map is not a function"

Comunidades.js has:

```
import React from 'react';

const ComunidadesAutonomas = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <label>Comunidades Autonomas</label>
            <select onChange={props.handleChange}>
                <option value="">Seleccione una Comunidad Autónoma</option>
                <option value="Euskadi">Comunidad Autónoma Vasca</option>
                <option value="Aragon">Aragon</option>
                <option value="Canarias">Canarias</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ComunidadesAutonomas;
```

provincias.js:

````
const Provincias = (props) => {
    return(<>
        <div>
            <label>Provincias</label>
            <select onChange={props.handleChange}>
                <option value="">Seleccione una provincia</option>
                    { props.opciones.map((opcionProvincia)=>(
                        <option key={opcionProvincia} value={opcionProvincia}>
                            {opcionProvincia}
                        </option>

                    ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    </>);
};

export default Provincias;```

I know that the error is in props.options.map((opcionProvincia) and it must be a array but i dont know how to solve.
````

Comment: `setProvinciasOpciones(selectedValue)` in `handleProvinciasChange` will change the type from array to string, thus causing your error